How to access a Swing UI component without its variable name?
I wanted to create Buttons by clicking on a Button with following code:
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        projects_panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
});

Now I wanted to change the text of the button with a TextField, but how do I access a specific UI component without knowing their name.
I tried naming the buttons with increasing numbers attached to a string, but this did not work. I also read that Java doesn't have this feature.

If you click the button 5 times and then  enter text in the JTextField, how do you know which button to update? Is it always the last created button? Is it the last button that you clicked on? Maybe you can use the getComponent(...) method of the JPanel you add the button to and get the last button in the container. Or maybe you need to add a FocusListener to the button and track the last button with focus. The requirement is not clear enough to provide a solution.

“Also I read that Java doesn't have this feature.”  I’m not sure to what feature you’re referring, specifically, but there are plenty of ways to associate a button with a text field.  If you edit your question and tell us more about why you’re adding buttons, we can probably suggest ways to do it.  For example, you can store them in a List, or you can store them as values in a Map.


How to access a Swing UI component without its variable name?

    /**
     * This returns the first showing Component that matches a given name.
     *
     * @param components leave this completely empty to search ALL showing components.
     */
    public static Component findComponentByName(String name, Component... components) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        if (components.length == 0)
            components = Window.getWindows();
        for (Component c : components) {
            if (c.isShowing()) {
                if (name.equals(c.getName())) {
                    return c;
                } else if (c instanceof Container container) {
                    Component[] children = container.getComponents();
                    if (children.length > 0) {
                        Component returnValue = findComponentByName(name, children);
                        if (returnValue != null)
                            return returnValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

(Also: remember a JComponent's name and its text are not the same. See JComponent.setName(String) and JButton.setText(String) )
But that method still leaves you pretty far from your goal:

Now i wanted to change the text of the button with a TextField

Here's some potential starter code:
package com.pump.winnow;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This panel has an "Add Project" button. Every time you click it a new JButton is created. When it is first
 * created: a JTextField sits on top of the JButton to let you edit the button's name. You can also enter this
 * special editing mode by right-clicking the JButton.
 */
public class ProjectPanel extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.getContentPane().add(new ProjectPanel());
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This positions a JTextField over a button. It assumes the button will only ever have one child (the JTextField),
     * or no children.
     */
    static class ButtonTextEditorLayout implements LayoutManager {
        private final JButton button;
        private final Dimension prefSize, minSize;

        public ButtonTextEditorLayout(JButton button) {
            this.button = button;
            prefSize = button.getUI().getPreferredSize(button);
            minSize = button.getUI().getMinimumSize(button);
        }

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {}

        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {}

        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            if (button != parent) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            if (button.getComponentCount() == 0)
                return button.getUI().getPreferredSize(button);
            return prefSize;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            if (button != parent) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            if (button.getComponentCount() == 0)
                return button.getUI().getMinimumSize(button);
            return minSize;
        }

        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            if (button != parent) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            if (button.getComponentCount() == 1) {
                JTextField field = (JTextField) button.getComponent(0);
                Insets buttonInsets = button.getInsets();
                Insets fieldInsets = field.getInsets();
                field.setBounds(new Rectangle(buttonInsets.left - fieldInsets.left,
                        buttonInsets.top - fieldInsets.top,
                        button.getWidth() - buttonInsets.left - buttonInsets.right + fieldInsets.left + fieldInsets.right,
                        button.getHeight() - buttonInsets.top - buttonInsets.bottom + fieldInsets.top + fieldInsets.bottom));
            }
        }
    }


    JPanel toolbar = new JPanel();
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Project");

    JPanel content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    public ProjectPanel() {
        toolbar.setBackground(Color.gray);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        toolbar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        toolbar.add(addButton);

        addButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            String projectName = "Project #" + (content.getComponentCount() + 1);
            JButton projectButton = new JButton(projectName);
            content.add(projectButton);
            setupButtonTextEditor(projectButton);
            revalidate();

            projectButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                // IIRC different platforms use different mouse events as popup triggers
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.isPopupTrigger())
                        setupButtonTextEditor(projectButton);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.isPopupTrigger())
                        setupButtonTextEditor(projectButton);
                }
            });
        });

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    }

    private void setupButtonTextEditor(JButton button) {
        JTextField field = new JTextField(button.getText());
        field.setBorder(null);
        field.setFont(button.getFont());
        field.addActionListener(e -> {
            removeTextField(button, field);
        });
        field.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                removeTextField(button, field);
            }
        });
        button.setLayout(new ButtonTextEditorLayout(button));
        button.add(field);

        field.selectAll();
        field.requestFocus();

        button.revalidate();
    }

    private void removeTextField(JButton button, JTextField field) {
        if (field.getParent() == button) {
            button.remove(field);
            button.setText(field.getText());
            button.repaint();
        }
    }
}

I would need mockups or more description to understand how to better meet your goal. I might (?) be inclined to create a custom JPanel for each project, and embed a permanent JTextField in that panel.
